# Laravel: Add Pagination to Json Response

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have an array for showing users' contacts list to each other.

I want to `add ->paginate(10)` features for json response but I could not find where I must put it.

My index function:

```
public function index()
{
    $contacts = [];
    $user = request()->user();
    // Loop through the contacts and format each one

    Contact::for($user->id)->get()->each(function ($contact) use ($user, &$contacts) {
        $friend = $contact->user1_id === $user->id ? $contact->user2 : $contact->user1;
        $contacts[] = $friend->toArray() + ['room' => $contact->room->toArray()];
    });

    return response()->json($contacts);
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what you are doing in the index()?

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar I am using pusher service for instant chat app, so I want to show created chat contacts to users like whatsapp. Im showing created chat lists to users at this index() function, its working well but I want to add pagination to it for infinite scroll.

Comment: Looks like you are doing thing in a complex way. Any way i will post a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a collection for the contact and use LenfthAwarePaginator

```
 class ContactResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
/**
 * Transform the resource into an array.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($request)
{
    $response = [
        'data' => $this->collection,
    ];

    if($this->resource instanceof LengthAwarePaginator)
    {
        $response['pagination'] = [
            'total' => $this->resource->total(),
            'lastPage' => $this->resource->lastPage(),
            'perPage' => $this->resource->perPage(),
            'currentPage' => $this->resource->currentPage(),
            'nextPageUrl' => $this->resource->nextPageUrl(),
            'previousPageUrl' => $this->resource->previousPageUrl(),
        ];
    }
    return $response;
  }
}
```

In the controller method add this line:

```
 return new UserResourceCollection($users);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I think there will be easiest way to do it, if I can not find easiest way I am gonna review this method, thanks :)

Comment: I tried so many things but lastly this method worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the total code

```
$contacts = Contact::where('user_id', $user->id)->paginate(12);
if($contacts->count()){                    
    $pageIndex = array();
    $lastPage = $contacts->lastPage();
    $user = request()->user();

    for($i= 2; $i<=$lastPage; $i++){
        array_push($pageIndex, $i);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'contacts' => $contacts->map(function ($contact) use ($user) {
                          if($contact->user1_id  === $user->id){

                            return [
                                'friend' => $contact->user2,
                                'room' => $contact->room,

                            ];

                        } else {

                            return [

                                    'friend' => $contact->user1,
                                    'room' => $contact->room,
                            ]; 

                        }
                    })->toArray(),  
        'per_page' => $contacts->perPage(),
        'on_first_page' => $contacts->onFirstPage(),
        'last_page' => $contacts->lastPage(),
        'first_page_url' => $contacts->url(1),
        'next_page_url' => $contacts->nextPageUrl(),
        'prev_page_url' => $contacts->previousPageUrl(),
        'last_page_url' => $contacts->url($contacts->lastPage()),
        'total' => $contacts->total(),
        'pageIndexArray' => $pageIndex,
        'errors' => false,
    ]);
} else {

  // Do Nothing
}
```

Call 
GET `'URL?page='+Page_index to get the response in JS (AJAX)`

Comment: I tried to edit my code with looking at your code but I could not combined it correct, Im not so good at Laravel, Can you combine it for me ? Thanks :)

Comment: sure, can you explain what you are doing here  $friend = $contact->user1_id === $user->id ? $contact->user2 : $contact->user1;
        $contacts[] = $friend->toArray() + ['room' => $contact->room->toArray()]

Comment: if you review this tutorial you can understand what Im trying to doing 
(Scroll down little bit and look at "THE CONTACTS ENDPOINT" please) https://pusher.com/tutorials/ios-chat-app-swift-chatkit-part-2#creating-our-endpoints
 He explained it like this; In the index method, we get all the contacts of the user and loop through each contact and append the contact to the contacts array. Finally we return the contacts as the response.

Comment: If you can , please give me the print_r($contacts[]); so that i can know what you meant

Comment: I did made this controller function for mobile app so I dont have any view for print it on web, is json result enough for understand ? Json Result : https://0bin.net/paste/WLY6DwFcmLzS5yBo#5LTEDczywJDW8VpD+V8Q00-lk3VeLNyF/AUlGfCcpPA

Comment: @Halilibrahimyüce I edited the code please check, if you find any difficulty feel free to ask. By the way, I worked with pusher API. If you need any backend support please ping me.

Comment: thanks sir, I did checked your code but I took "Undefined variable: user" error but I did already solved this problem thanks :)

Comment: @Halilibrahimyüce Its my pleasure, $user is defined i think. i dont know how that appeared :(. Can you please upvote / accepted answer, this will be a huge support for me.

Comment: I have choosed answer of @eva as accepted, it worked well :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try : replace `get()` to `paginate(10)`

```
Contact::for($user->id)->paginate(10)->each(function ($contact) use ($user, &$contacts) {
        $friend = $contact->user1_id === $user->id ? $contact->user2 : $contact->user1;
        $contacts[] = $friend->toArray() + ['room' => $contact->room->toArray()];
    });
```

Comment: I did tried this one but it was not work, thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the query into:

```
$contacts = Contact::for($user->id)->paginate(10);
```

Then after this query you can use `for loop` for `$contact`;

```
 foreach ($contacts as $key => $contact)
 {
   $friend = $contact->user1_id === $user->id ? $contact->user2 : $contact->user1;
   $contacts[] = $friend->toArray() + ['room' => $contact->room->toArray()];
 }
```

Paginate first before get into loop/each.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did made this changes but it changed json results ?

Comment: since we have a variable of `$contacts` you can change your `$contacts = [];` into `$contact_array = [];` and change other variable name handling the array., then return code `return response()->json($contact_array);`

Comment: I did made this changes too but its showing empty json results :/

Full code;

`public function index()
    {
        $contact_array = [];
        $user = request()->user();

        $contacts = Contact::for($user->id)->paginate(10);

        foreach ($contacts as $key => $contact)
 {
   $friend = $contact->user1_id === $user->id ? $contact->user2 : $contact->user1;
   $contacts[] = $friend->toArray() + ['room' => $contact->room->toArray()];
 }


        return response()->json($contact_array);
    }`

Comment: try these

`public function index() { 
    $contact_array = [];
     $user = request()->user(); 
     $contacts = Contact::for($user->id)->paginate(10); 
     foreach ($contacts as $key => $contact) 
     { $friend = $contact->user1_id === $user->id ? $contact->user2 : $contact->user1; 
     $contact_array[] = $friend->toArray() + ['room' => $contact->room->toArray()]; 
     } return response()->json($contact_array); 
}`

Comment: Thanks it works again but like before these changes. it does not added pagination :/

Comment: i need to verify what's your schema why you are using `for` in this query `Contact::for($user->id)` do you have `user_id`  or any `id` that reference.

and how many data in your contacts?

Comment: if you review this tutorial you can understand what Im trying to doing
(Scroll down little bit and look at "THE CONTACTS ENDPOINT" please)

https://pusher.com/tutorials/ios-chat-app-swift-chatkit-part-2#creating-our-endpoints

He explained it like this;

In the index method, we get all the contacts of the user and loop through each contact and append the contact to the contacts array. Finally we return the contacts as the response.

Comment: remember that `paginate` method is the number of items you wish to display per page. try to put 15 data and use `paginate(10)` then we can check if its paginate pero page, for limit you can use `limit`. Please try `take(10)`

Comment: yeah I know but even if there is not any item its showing current page, next page or somethings, I did try it with paginate(1) too but its same :)

Comment: even you tried `paginate(1)` or `paginate(2)` the data will appear?

Comment: yeah data will appear but for example if I tried paginate(1), its showing just one item. If I tried paginate(2) its showing 2 items but there is not pagination

Comment: Json Result according to your shared last codes;

https://0bin.net/paste/WLY6DwFcmLzS5yBo#5LTEDczywJDW8VpD+V8Q00-lk3VeLNyF/AUlGfCcpPA